# Is there a control in FMX (mobile) that supports RGB color?

Tags: colors, firemonkey

I need to change the **control's color** to several tones of gray at runtime...

Comment: All FMX controls support RGB color. Though many colors are defined as color constants you can set your own RGB values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just a coloured shape on the form, consider shape controls and this snippet for a TRectangle on the form:

```
Rectangle1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColor(TAlphaColorRec.Aliceblue);
Rectangle1.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
```

A TAlphaColor cast here is for mobiles.

To set color parts separately use this snippet:

```
var
  col: TAlphaColorRec;
begin
  col.R := 255;
  col.G := 255;
  col.B := 255;
  col.A := 255;
  Rectangle1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColor(col);
  Rectangle1.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
end;
```